# Found a typo in the API docs

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, wording

I was looking through the [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-question) for creating a new question using the SA API, I think there is a typo:
[image]

> This method return the created question.

I think should be

> This method returns the created question.

Just wanted to let you all know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you, there were 7 such occurrences. I've corrected them and the fix will be deployed shortly.

Comment: BTW, there are a few posts about typos on Stack Apps: [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/6899/few-typos-in-the-documentation-pages) and [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/6893/typos-on-api-stackexchange-com-docs-js-lib)... would it be possible to fix them as well? They seem to have gone unnoticed over on Stack Apps! :)